# which is the best framework for angular testing?

Tags: angularjs

Please suggest the best angularjs testing framework

Comment: This question is strongly opinion-based and couldn't be posted in SO

Comment: I m newbie ....................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma is used by the angular team as the test case runner and can be considered as the standard. And jasmine is the best framework for automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended Unit Testing Tools

```
Jasmine - "Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code." (personal favourite, awesome docs)

Mocha - "The fun, simple, flexible JavaScript test framework."

QUnit - "A JavaScript Unit Testing framework, used by jQuery."
```

Jasmine is the best testing among these.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jasmine framework with angularjs and it is good you can use this